# Sidekiq rails not performing job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

Home Controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController


    def index
        if request.post?
          @value = (params[:value] || 10).to_i 
          # Perform the calculation of the fibonnaci in background
          puts('starting job...')
          TestJob.perform_async("Luis",@value)
        end

        # Retrieve from Redis the last 10 calculations
        @bottom = redis.lrange("calcs",-10,-1).reverse
    end

    private
     def redis
    @redis ||= Redis.new
  end
end
```

HTML erb File (View)

```
Fibonnaci calculator (try a few between 30 and 40)
<%= form_tag(home_index_path) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:value,@value) %>
  <%= submit_tag(:calculate) %>
<% end %>

Past completed calculations
<ul>
  <% @bottom.each do |value| %>
    <li><%= value %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

TestJob class

```
class TestJob
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  # Calculate the nth fibonnaci sequence number
  def fib(x)
    return 0 if x < 1
    x < 3 ? 1 : fib(x-1) + fib(x-2)
  end

  # Sidekiq has the same interface as resque, so we can call this method asynchronously by using SlowJob.perform_async
  # When #perform_async is called the arguments are serialized to a Redis queue and later our background job processor
  # will dequeue them and call the #perform method below with them
  def perform(name, number)
    time = Time.now
    # Recursive Fibonnaci of larger than 30 numbers can take a while
    result = fib(number)
    duration = Time.now - time

    text =  "Dear #{name} the Fibonacci value of #{number} is #{result} (#{"%.2f" % duration }) #{time.strftime("%F %T")}"

    # Put the results in a redis list so we can see them on the web interface at each new request
    redis.rpush "calcs", text
  end

  # Create a redis client
  def redis
    @redis ||= Redis.new
  end
end
```

So when I submit the form on HTML, forexample I put 5 in form then post request is successfully sent and i see absolutely no errors.

I see this output in console:

```
Started POST "/home/index" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-05 17:23:35 +0530
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"cgQMV3sCP91zaeiPfYVC5mxfBZpDmgKgRZ7qe5PWCdqGUX59v8I4BZoKXbdYlqfsLyp6/cz8XY/3cEXe/mKh4A==", "value"=>"5", "commit"=>"calculate"}
starting job...
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 81ms (Views: 76.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

And I don't see anything in HTML file.
Job is not getting performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you start sidekiq worker?

```
bundle exec sidekiq
```